# OfficeJS Outlook mailbody getasync added extra styles for the <p> tag

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am using getAsync method to retrieve the outlook body. but the value doesnot have correct styles on

tag

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync("html", { asyncContext: event }, function(result) {
  console.log(result.value);
});
```

Original text is this

```
<p><span style="font-family:Arial,sans-serif;">If you’re available, what’s the best way to schedule?</span></p>
```

but from the getAsync I got this

```
<p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;"><span style="font-weight:400">If you’re available, what’s the best way to schedule?</span></p>
```

it means got a extra style for the

tag `style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;"` also it removes the styles for fonts in  tag.

Is it office js behavior or Any fix for this ?

Comment: In which Platform are you facing this issue?

Comment: Issue occurred in OWA

Comment: We are not able to repro this issue. Can you provide more details?
1. Is this issue specific to any browser?
2. How is the body being set here? Is this being done using Body APIs?